# How to rename a Windows 10 machine using command line

Tags: cmd, command-line, windows-10, rename

I am tasked with renaming a couple of customers machines with new names. I would like to do it without interrupting the customers. We use DATTO remote system and can start a CMD prompt with the machine with admin privilege's without disturbing the user. The command I tried is below:

```
wmic ComputerSystem where "name='%ComputerName%'" call rename VS-R-REM-02
Invalid verb switch
```

I am getting this invalid verb switch error, anyone know how to fix? I don't think I have access to powershell without remoting in, just CMD.

Thanks,

Comment: I suppose it depends upon what you mean by not interupting the customers! My best guess would be that a reboot would be required for a computername change to be properly implemented, and I'm going to suggest that your customers would notice everything shutting down, then a reboot!

Comment: Yes, but it does not need to be rebooted immediately. I would like to change the name, inform them to turn off their machine by the end of the day and then it will be changed. Regardless, the error I am running into still stands.

Comment: What happens when you use the full syntax? `@"%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe" ComputerSystem Where "Name='%COMPUTERNAME%'" Call Rename Name="NewName"`. There may also be no need for the `Where` clause, so perhaps this would suffice, `@"%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe" ComputerSystem Call Rename Name="NewName"`. Also, I don't know exactly how your remote access software works, so perhaps just having 'admin privileges', may not necessarily mean that you have the required token to perform the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already to save yourself connecting to each computer individually you can write yourself a component either as a batch file or PowerShell script and run the newly created component as a job.

PowerShell should be something along the lines of:

Workstation:

```
Rename-Computer -NewName "ComputerName" -LocalCredential localhostAdminUser
```

Domain Joined:

```
Rename-Computer -NewName "ComputerName" -DomainCredential DomainAdminUser
```

If you want to know more about Rename-Computer cmdlet, check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-computer?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6